# Chart.js equivalent for React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I want to get interactive charts to work in my React Native app. I know there's probably not a React Native specific library made yet, but what Objective-C/Swift/Javascript library should I be looking into that would allow me to make charts/graphs that look like the ones Chart.js generate?

Comment: For charting in React Native and React, use Victory:
https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery

Answer (score 7):

I would go for [ART library](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/ART) of the react-native project.

Here is a [chart example](http://browniefed.com/blog/2015/05/29/react-art-and-bar-charts/) for ReactJS that you could adapt for react-native, by looking at these [React-native Art](http://browniefed.com/blog/2015/10/14/react-native-morphing-svg-paths-with-react-art/) examples.

Also, there is probably something to investigate with [Chartist library](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) which use SVG to draw charts, and that has a [reactjs component](http://fraserxu.me/react-chartist/).

EDIT: As of version 0.18rc, React-Native also support [ART library for Android](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/27ac04742ab4665cd529fe63fd68a30db9293b76).

Comment: http://fraserxu.me/react-chartist/ looks promising.  Do you know if this should be compatible with react-native?  I do not understand how to determine compatibility with react-native.  In my experience, if it does not have "react-native-*" prefix, it will not work.  ( I am a Javascript and react-native newbie )

Comment: react-chartist is written for the browser, so not compatible with react-native (I didn't try but should work in a webview). To draw "native" chart, all the drawing logic needs to be written...

Comment: Thanks @Sulliwane. I will give webview + react-chartist a try.  It should be worth the time investment.  I can find no react-native chart component that supports *both* Android and iOS.

Comment: @EdoftheMountain did you manage to get this working by any chance? Trying to get a graph running in my R Native app but finding no luck :/

Comment: For charting in React Native and React, use Victory:
https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery

Answer (score 3):

You'll be wanting to look at Obj-C and Swift, not JavaScript I think. Existing JS libraries will be drawing to the DOM, Canvas or some other browser target that won't be available in React Native. That should narrow the field a bit. Then to use it direct from RN you need to create a [Native Module](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#content) between JS and Obj-C.

So at that point it boils down to: "what's a good iOS charting library" and fortunately someone's already done the hard work on that one [over on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724887/ios-chart-libraries). [Core Plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Example-Graphs) looks pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Could I use something like this, https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-canvas? I still am thinking it won't work for react native because I would need to override the chartjs canvas with this react native canvas. Just trying to figure what is possible and reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tomauty/react-native-chart has been available for a while.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.